# Profile detail animation in sheet swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I tried to create a sheet with user details. When tried to expand the sheet, the detail should align in left side with animation. I tried using matched geometry and it crashes with message "com.apple.SwiftUI.AsyncRenderer (11): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1a69151cc)".

I created two Vstack in the sheet and check with a variable isProfileExpanded. This variable is changing in onchange of sheet as:

```
struct ProfileListView: View {

@State var navigateToActivityDetail: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $navigateToActivityDetail) {
        ProfileDetailDetailView()
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large, .fraction(0.75)])
            .background(Color(ColorConstants.GeneralElevation1).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
}
```

}

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack(spacing: 32) {
            VStack {
                DrawerStateUser(isProfileExpanded: $isProfileExpanded)
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            
        }
        .onChange(of: proxy.size.height, perform: { newValue in
                    if newValue > (screenSize().size.height*0.6) {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            self.isProfileExpanded = false
                        }
                    } else {
                        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                            self.isProfileExpanded = true
                        }
                    }
            }
        })
        .padding(.top, 40)
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The height observer will get called frequently and updates `isProfileExpanded` might be the reason for crash.

Instead of observing the height change, observe the detent value changes. And you can update the `isProfileExpanded` to true when the detent matches your desired value.

```
struct ProfileDetailDetailView: View {
  // setting initial size to .medium.
  @State var presentationDetent: PresentationDetent = .medium

 var body: some View {
   DrawerStateUser(isProfileExpanded: $isProfileExpanded)
     // moved presentationDetents modifier from ProfileListView to here.
     .presentationDetents([.medium, .large, .fraction(0.75)], selection: $presentationDetent)
     .onChange(of: presentationDetent, perform: { value in
         print("Changed")
         withAnimation(.spring()) {
            if presentationDetent == .large {
               isProfileExpanded = true
            } else {
               isProfileExpanded = false
            }
         }
      })
  }
}
```

This will trigger the animations when user triggers large size. But this approach doesn't render size as the users scrolls up.
For that, you have to make the size changes programatically based on the user's scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is to create an extension to Switch between `VStack` and `HStack` first:

```
extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func vStakcOrHstack(isVstack: Bool = false) -> some View {
        if isVstack {
            VStack {
                self
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .top)
        } else {
            HStack {
                self
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow to pass a boolean when when **true** renders a `VStack`, or an `HStack` otherwise.

Then the rest of the code is as follow:

```
@State private var isProfileExpanded = false

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack(spacing: 32) {
            Profile(isVertical: isProfileExpanded)
            
            Button("Switch") {
                withAnimation(/* YOUR PREFERRED ANIMATION HERE */) {
                    self.isProfileExpanded.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
    
}

@ViewBuilder func Profile(isVertical: Bool = false) -> some View {
    Group {
        Circle()
            .fill(.red)
            .frame(width: 100)
        VStack {
            Text("Full Name")
            
            Text("Other Text")
        }
    }
    .vStakcOrHstack(isVstack: isVertical)
}
```

Of course, I don't know exactly how you would like the animation to be since the images you posted are static and there is also no [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You will maybe need to adjust the code for your needs.

I used the `matched geometry` by the way it works in my code:

```
@Namespace var namespace

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack(spacing: 32) {
            Profile(isVertical: isProfileExpanded)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "ID", in: namespace)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            Button("Switch") {
                withAnimation(/* YOUR PREFERRED ANIMATION HERE */) {
                    self.isProfileExpanded.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
    
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Matched Geometry]

I hope to have helped you with this.

Comment: This is good. But What I was looking for is a smooth animation. In a sheet. If sheet is in medium style the profile detail should be in centre and if sheet is in large style the detail should be in left side. Please check the animation in this tutorial. Here he is animating with button click. What I need is the animation with scroll. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7OuerHs8PU

Comment: There is not even a sheet in the code you provided.Why don't you follow the tutorial?